# What short story has a robot nanny who needed to be replaced, and a plot twist?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

Around 2014 I read a short story collection; in the collection there was a story about a futuristic world where people had nanny bots to look after and entertain their children. In the story a nanny bot breaks down and I remember something about a box with the new nanny in showing up and them assembling it.

I do not know very much more of this story, other then the plot-twist:

> as it turns out their kid is also a robot they bought.

As it is a memory of long ago the details of the story I provided can be faulty but I am sure of the twist.

What story is this? Would love to find and read the collection again

---

It is not *Nanny* (1955) by Philip K. Dick, as answered below.
It is not *Supertoys Last All Summer Long* by Brian Aldiss,as answered below.

Comment: You read it around 8 years and a few months ago (in 2013-2014)?

Comment: Please include the details of the plot twist; you can hide spoilers by starting the line with `>!`.

Comment: I've read it only one time 8y ago and it just now popped in my head after seeying a movie related to androids

Comment: A similar plot twist is used in W. F. Nolans "And Miles to Go Before I Sleep" (1958) - a astronaut dying on a deep space mission sends a robot double to his parents as a deceit to comfort them, and the parents have had robot doubles of themselves created before their death. Just if you are generally interested in that trope :-)

Comment: Since its not mentioned yet, this doesn't seem to be [Robbie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbie_(short_story)), a short story about a robot nanny by Asimov.  (It doesn't have the plot twist mentioned)

Comment: I have been looking into Asimov as the themes of his books are very alike

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you are thinking of ["Nanny" (1955) by Philip K. Dick](https://philipkdickreview.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/nanny/)?

(It is the answer to [some other](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218482/1970s-80s-short-story-compilation-anthology-where-eating-real-food-is-illegal-an/) [robot nanny replacement questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142446/color-coded-household-robots-that-kept-needing-upgrades/) on this site.)

> "Nanny" is a science fiction short story by American writer Philip K. Dick, first published in 1955 in Startling Stories and later in The Collected Stories of Philip K. Dick . It has since been republished several times, including in Beyond Lies the Wub in 1988. ([source](https://wikimili.com/en/Nanny_(short_story)))

You can read the full story [here](https://archive.org/details/Startling_Stories_v33n01_1955-Spring/page/n49/mode/2up?view=theater).

**Points in common with your description:**

- Found in bundle of short stories
- Pre-2013
- Broken nanny robot who needs to be replaced (because after being repeatedly damaged when fighting other nanny robots, it was eventually killed in one such fight)

**Points not in common with your description:**

- None of the kids are robots; instead, the new nanny ends up

> killing another nanny robot.

Comment: Thanks for your responds ! However I've gone through it and it is not the story I am searching for.

Comment: amazing idea for a story, good old PKD! also I am surprised as a Dickhead that i never saw this story -- i am sure I would remember.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it could be [Supertoys Last All Summer Long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertoys_Last_All_Summer_Long) by Brian Aldiss.

It features a child with a robot companion Teddy, and has the same plot twist:

> At the end, it's revealed that the child is a robot.

Related to the plot twist:

> "The short story was later used as the basis for the first act of the feature film A.I. Artificial Intelligence directed by Steven Spielberg in 2001."

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have read the story but I don't think it is the one I am looking for.